# Catboost predicton return error Feature Marked different in dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, yandex, catboost

I trained binary classifier with catboost, same featues in test data it return this error;

```
catboost/libs/data/model_dataset_compatibility.cpp:47: Feature MERCHANT_ID is Categorical in model but marked different in the dataset
```

What does it mean, anyone have an idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like MERCHANT_ID is handled as categorical column during training (fit stage), and you provided its index as categorical column, but during predict on the test data either MERCHANT_ID has a different type, or your columns shifted, thus the model expect to see the column in a different index location.

verify that the column positions in X_train and X_test are the same.